# Counting JdbcTemplate queries

Tags: java, h2, spring-jdbc

We have a requirement to count the number of queries (and the number of result rows) our web application sends to the database for each request. We can easily implement this by counting manually (each time `JdbcTemplate.query*` is called, increment a counter), but this is easy to forget about in the future which would lead to incorrect results.

Is there a way to add an interceptor to the JdbcTemplate or DataSource which could do this for us, or alternatively is there any way to validate the results when using a test database such as H2 so that we can at least prove correctness?

Comment: It seems you need a query listener here.

Comment: What kind of logging does H2 provide?  Perhaps correlate H2 logged queries with the app's IP.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to intercept the JDBC driver using e.g. [JDBCSpy](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jdbcspy/).

> Features
>
> - log the execution and the iteration time of all SQL statements
> - identify statements that are executed multiple times
> - the stack trace with configurable depth for all listed statements
> - provides statistics for all connections, SQL statements, resultsets
> - provides the size of the resultset
> - provides an API to retrieve all statistical information
> - list all statements that are currently being executed
> - list all statements that have been executed, but have not been closed
> - notifies (e.g. via trace) if a statement's execution time exceeds a configurable threshold
> - notifies if you forgot to close a resultset, or a statement before the connection is closed
> - supports different loggers (log4j, java logging, slf, ...)
> - extendable by custom listeners

The project seems to be no longer actively maintained but it should give you a starting point. By intercepting JDBC you will ensure that no matter how the query is executed e.g. manual `Connection`, `JdbcTemplate`, or JPA all the queries will be intercepted.